# PWM - RPM - propeller thrust

Tags: pwm, dc-motor

Imagine a 20mm dc motor with a simple plastic propeller controlled by a microcontroller via PWM.

Consider the following correlations:

- PWM - RPM
- RPM - thrust
- PWM - thrust

Are they proportional?
If not, what kind of correlations have they? And what makes them not proportional?

Comment: If, by 'linear', you mean one is a constant x the other at all values of time, then PWM-RPM is not linear. There's a transient.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant... what's the correct word in English for that?

Comment: 'one-to-one correspondence' means that each value of A is related to a unique value of B. 'Proportional to' means two variables are related by a constant multiplier. 'Linear' has interpretations, other than straight line, in dynamic systems.

Comment: So in this image (I picked it up randomly on Google) "Resistenza" (y axis) is proportional to "Posizione" (x)? (that's what I meant with linear)

Comment: Cant see the image, but if its a (straight) line, yes!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't paste the link. Here: http://www.pd.infn.it/~lunardon/didattica/LibEsp3/CalibPotR6.gif

Comment: So, in that sense, there is not a linear relationship between PWM and RPM

Comment: so, what kind of relationship is there?